# Python3 KeyError: 'Data' - But Source JSON and Python Line Appear To Match

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get better at Python. I found blog post (https://www.brettfullam.com/security-automation-with-python-ip-address-and-url-analysis-via-virus-totals-api-v-3-with-html-reporting) about a script that will take an IP or URL, or list of either, hit the Virus Total API with the data and collect and format the results. The

When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\nick_\Projects\python-vt-apiv3\vt-ip-url- 
analysis.py", line 454, in <module>urlReport(args.single_entry)
File "c:\Users\nick_\Projects\python-vt-apiv3\vt-ip-url- 
analysis.py", line 104, in urlReport epoch_time = 
(decodedResponse["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_date"])
KeyError: 'data'
```

From what I understand the value "data" is missing from the source the script is reading from.

I've gone into the script and read the blog post and discovered the following:

```
File "c:\Users\nick_\Projects\python-vt-apiv3\vt-ip-url-analysis.py", line 454, in <module>
urlReport(args.single_entry)
```

This part of the traceback is where the script detects that I've entered one entry and then calls another part of the urlReport function which leads to here:

```
File "c:\Users\nick_\Projects\python-vt-apiv3\vt-ip-url-analysis.py", line 104, in urlReport
epoch_time = (decodedResponse["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_date"])
```

What's happening here is decodedResponse is the variable defined by the response received from Virus Total as described here on line 89:
# load returned json from virustotal into a python dictionary called decodedResponse
decodedResponse = json.loads(response.text)

According to the Virus total documentation this is the json being returned and converted into a dictionary (I shortened it to what is relevant)

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "categories": {dict},
      "favicon": {
        "dhash": "<string>",
        "raw_md5": "<string>"
      },
      "first_submission_date": <int:timestamp>,
      "html_meta": {
        "<str:tag_name>": ["<tag_value:string>"]
      },
      "last_analysis_date": <int:timestamp>,
```

So I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with this line:

```
epoch_time = (decodedResponse["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_date"])
```

It seems to be formatted correctly to grab the time stamp value from the last_analysis_date key.

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong? The blog post and script are from 2 years ago so I'm wondering if VT changed their JSON format and the way this script is calling the value from the dictionary isn't formatted properly? I just can't see how based on other responses I've read to similar questions.

Thanks for reading!